# What are the benefits of an FAA over an ICAO license, and vice versa?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification, icao

I will study for commercial pilot in May but I don´t know where I should study. I have 2 really good schools, one is in Canada (ICAO) the other one is in Florida (FAA),

What are the advantages and/or differences of both licenses when it comes to a career in international aviation and what potential differences may it have in career and training paths.

If we only talk about license not about schools.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Aviation StackExchange. `prestige` - this might be a translation error.  Please could you try different words to describe exactly what you mean.

Comment: I have edited this to drive more factual and less opinionated answers as per the guidelines of this exchange.

Comment: There's not really such a thing as an 'ICAO licence' for pilots. You will get either a Canadian or a US licence, and if you then get a job in Dubai you'll need to convert the licence to a UAE one. The linked question should clear it up a bit. FWIW, the US licences are a bit more annoying to convert in my experience, as the US doesn't comply with the ICAO English language requirements, so US pilots often have to take another English test. Go figure!